# ChromeDriver stopped working after reinstall.. Worked fine before - no other changes made. (macOS)

Tags: bash, macos, selenium

I'm new to Selenium webdriver but the issue that I am running into does not seem like a common problem (looked everywhere for solutions for 4+ hours).

> macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 - Selenium 3.13.0 [**via pip3**] -
>   ChromeDriver 2.40 [**via web source**] - Chrome 68 - Python 3.7

**Here's what happened:**

- Initially chromedriver is in my Applications directory with .bashrc and .bash_profile including:
  `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin:/Applications"`
- I was building a scraper in Python 3.7 everything is working fine executing from command line:

  `python3.7 scraper.py`
- I want to start running scraper.py from inside SublimeText3.
- I copy chromedriver into `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/bin` to be available for my python3 Sublime build system.
- Doesn't work: something to do with it not being the original.
- Accidentally deleted original.... So I remove all traces of chromedriver and redownload to Applications directory (**original working conditions**).
- Now, I try to run again from command line and I'm getting `Only local connections are allowed.`
- I try to execute `chromedriver` on the command line and I get `bash: command not found`. **Even when I am in the Applications directory!** Whereas before I could execute `chromedriver` from any directory.
- Every solution online suggests that it's either a compatibility issue or a PATH issue but neither is the case.
- Tried rebooting my system, reinstalling python, reinstalling Selenium, reinstalling chromedriver again, moving chromedriver/redirecting PATH, rebooting my system again, everything...

Any input would be greatly appreciated. I'm thinking it has more to do with the OS then anything else. But can't make heads or tails of this. Also wondering if using a virtualenv would be able to circumvent this issue?

**UPDATE:** To anyone experiencing a similar issue, I would recommend just using a virtualenv. This allows you to work in an isolated python environment without having to clutter up your system with global packages and potentially risking a bug in your system's configuration.

Comment: If you see the error `bash: command not found` it's a configuration issue and not related to `Selenium`

Comment: Installing an executable in the root of `/Applications`, and therefore having this in your `$PATH`, is very undesirable! After you installed chromedriver - your "original working conditions" - run `which chromedriver`; what do you get?